# How can I trigger a buttton click event at regular intervals?

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to make an idle clicker game like Adventure Capitalist. I have created the script for the buttons (say button-type: buy) that would increase the gold and the script to upgrade the gold per click (button-type :upgrade). Now I want to create a C# script for a button(button-type: auto clicker) that would enable me to automatically click those button at regular intervals?

These are my scripts:

```
public class Click : MonoBehaviour {

    public Gold gold;
    public float gpc;
    public Text goldCount;
    public float price;
    public int active = 0;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        goldCount.text = "$" + gold.gold;
    }

    public void Activate()
    {
        if(active == 0)
        {
            if(gold.gold >= price)
            {
                gold.gold -= price;
                active = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Clicked()
    {
        if(active == 1)
        {
            gold.gold += gpc;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Gold : MonoBehaviour {
    public float gold;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

---

```
public class UpgradeManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Click click;
    public Gold gold;
    public float upgradeCost;
    public int count;
    public int clickPower;
    public string itemName;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    public void PurchasedUpgrade()
    {
        if(gold.gold >= upgradeCost)
        {
            gold.gold -= upgradeCost;
            count++;
            click.gpc = clickPower;
            upgradeCost = Mathf.Round(upgradeCost * Mathf.Pow(1.15f, count));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have something interval related and I don't want to bother with `InvokeRepeating` + `CancelInvoke` combo or a coroutine, I just use a generic timer.

Sample code:

```
float timerCheck = amountYouWantToCheckAgainst;
float timer = 0;

Update(){
    timer = timer + Time.deltaTime; //add time passed since last frame to your timer
    while(timer > timerCheck){
        Invoke("MethodName", 0); //call whatever method you'd like to call
        timer = timer - timerCheck //subtract timerCheck from timer
    }
}
```

The reason we subtract `timerCheck` from timer is because there might come a point where you'd like to call this function more than once after a frame, if we just checked against the `timerCheck` then it'd only run once.

Example situation:

> Let's say 10 miliseconds has passed since last frame and you wanted a
>   click every 3 miliseconds. If we reset the timer every time the event
>   happened, we'd get a click after that particular frame.
>
> By subtracting `timerCheck` from `timer` and looping we get to run the
>   function three times and we also don't lose our remaining timer amount
>   (which is 1 milisecond in this case).
>
> When the next frame comes around and you now want a click every 2.5
>   miliseconds and if we assume 9 miliseconds has passed since last
>   frame, we now have a timer that is equal to 10 miliseconds. On this
>   frame, the loop will run four times.

This does run the risk of going through a loop too many times and stalling the gameplay but since you need an auto-upgrade kind of thing, I assume you'll never see a problem like this.

If you need to click on many upgrades and you need different counters for all of them, then `InvokeRepeating` and `CancelInvoke` will work much better than this method in terms of performance.

Comment: This is pretty much how I do it too, although two things: 1) You don't need to use Invoke("MethodName",0); it'd be better to simply call MethodName(); in that case.

Comment: 2) I wouldn't actually call the method multiple times in a loop, but rather count how many times to update and then call the method once like MethodName(numRepeats); This is just to avoid having a whole cascade of UI code running over and over in a single frame, since there are probably bindings and/or event listeners triggered by MethodName.

Comment: @jhocking that would be the correct way to go about it. I like leaving some room for improvement in my answers, usually because it helps people learn other stuff by making mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use either an IEnumerator or Unity's InvokeRepeating:

`InvokeRepeating("method name", float start_delay, float interval_time);`

Answer (score 0):

I would check every Update() if it's time to activate, and increment the timer every frame regardless. Doing it with coroutines or other delayed execution would make it tricky to change the interval mid-stream, and in these sorts of games it's common to upgrade and change how long it takes while in the middle of waiting.

Comment: Why would it be tricky to change the interval in a coroutine? Unless I'm missing something, the only potential problem is that changes will not take effect until the next "cycle" when the coroutine re-awakens. But that's generally a non-issue.

Comment: er that's the precise issue actually. By "midstream" I *meant* "in the middle of an update cycle". If you consider that a non-issue, well that's up to your game design I suppose.

Comment: I would never use update for the very reason you say to use update. You don't have a lot of control over how fast Update is getting called, therefore managing an interval event requires more code, harder to read code, and is less efficient because it runs that code more often than needed. Coroutines or the invoke repeating is much easier to read and modify.

Comment: How exactly would you modify the timing of InvokeRepeating?

Comment: You couldn't with the InvokeRepeating unless you called CancelInvoke and then recalled InvokeRepeating with a different interval. I'd use IEnumerator if it needs to change. I suggested InvokeRepeating as the one line of code solution.

Answer (score 0):

InvokeRepeating would work, but you are very limited and cannot change the interval once you start.

I would use a coroutine instead

```
float interval;
IEnumerator pressButton(<insert args here>){
   while(condition){
      buttonClick();
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
   }
}
```

The advantage of coroutines is that you can modify those variables whenever / wherever you want and your code will work accordingly.

This can also allow your timescale to align with detla time and other factors if you so choose.

As per the discussion with jhocking, there is a potential complication in that any changes to data / interval would not take effect until after the current cycle completes (IE, changes will not be immediate). This problems directly relates to the length of your intervals. Shorter intervals will be significantly less noticeable, while longer ones will be more so.

if this is not a concern, it's the easiest and cleanest way to solve the problem (IMO).